# soap result to variable, PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am ignorant when it comes to SOAP.  I am performing a web service call:

```
<?php
// define the SOAP client using the url for the service
$client = new soapclient('http://www.xignite.com/xMetals.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));

// create an array of parameters 
$param = array(
           'Type' => "XAU",
           'Currency' => "USD");



// call the service, passing the parameters and the name of the operation 
$result = $client->GetLastRealTimeMetalQuote($param);
// assess the results 
if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
 echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '</pre>';
} else {
 echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

and when I run the script i get:

```
Result

stdClass Object
(
[GetLastRealTimeMetalQuoteResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Outcome] => Success
        [Identity] => IP
        [Delay] => 0.006
        [Symbol] => XAUUSDO
        [Type] => XAU
        [Currency] => USD
        [Date] => 8/1/2011
        [Time] => 11:18:48 PM
        [Rate] => 1618.88500977
        [Bid] => 1618.55004883
        [BidTime] => 11:18:48 PM
        [Ask] => 1619.2199707
        [AskTime] => 11:18:48 PM
    )

)
```

How do I separate the [Bid] out from the rest of the result and store it in a variable.

Or better yet how can I pull out the array?

Comment: Note that it is returning an OBJECT, not an ARRAY.  I've noticed with SOAP that these get all mixed up.  It's worse when a single object is returned in the first case, but multiple objects are returned in the second.  YOu need separate routines for each situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the stdClass object mix you up - this is simply an array that is represented with object notation.  So, `$result['GetLastRealTimeMetalQuoteResult']['Bid']` (a normal associative array) becomes `$result->GetLastRealTimeMetalQuoteResult->Bid` - same values, just a different notation.

You get stdClass objects when a value is typecast into an object, which the SOAP library does. See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php  For some more detail about stdClass, check out this article: http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass

If you'd like to convert the stdClass to an array, unfortunately you'll have to use a little function:

```
function objToArray($obj=false)  {
    if (is_object($obj))
        $obj= get_object_vars($obj);
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
    } else {
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$somevar = $result->GetLastRealTimeMetalQuoteResult->Bid;
```